# eager loading deeply nested relationships?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a series of tables related like so;

```
trainers -> hasMany -> programs
programs -> hasMany -> weeks
weeks -> hasMany -> days
days -> hasMany -> sessions
sessions -> hasMany -> phases
phases -> hasMany -> excersises
```

the relationships in the opposite direction are all has one accept for excersises to phases which is also hasMany with a pivot table

getting relationships one deep like this per the documentation works fine obviously

```
$programs = $this->program->orderBy('trainerId', 'asc')->take(1)->with('weeks.days')->get();
```

I need to be able to retrieve the contents of an entire program and I thought that I could eager load each nested relationship something like this

```
$programs = $this->program->orderBy('trainerId', 'asc')->take(1)->with('weeks.days', 'weeks.days.sessions')->get();
```

or

```
$programs = $this->program->orderBy('trainerId', 'asc')->take(1)->with('weeks.days.sessions')->get();
```

but both return a FatalErrorException

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::newQuery()

whats the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question, I can see you have nested relationship like the following.

```
programs -> hasMany -> weeks
-----------------------------weeks -> hasMany -> days
----------------------------------------------------days -> hasMany -> sessions
```

It is very hard to know what data should load for `days` if we do not know the `weeks`. Similarly for the `sessions` as well. So, we have to load the `weeks` data first then `days`, then `sessions`.

From Laravel documentation, we can see, Eager loading using the following approach:

```
select * from books

select * from authors where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...)
```

Laravel loading `author` data based on `books` data.

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading

Try to load `weeks` first

```
$programs = $this->program->orderBy('trainerId', 'asc')
   ->take(1)
   ->with('weeks', 'weeks.days', 'weeks.days.sessions')
   ->get();
```

**or:**

Lazy Eager Loading:

```
 $programs = $this->program->orderBy('trainerId', 'asc')->take(1)->get();

 $programs->load('weeks', 'weeks.days', 'weeks.days.sessions');
```

Comment: As this would work relative to the title, I will mark it as accepted but if someone is getting the same error I was please see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

So I found the problem and it might help someone else to know the answer.  this thread gave me the aha moment [laravel forums](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=12646)

I have a model called Session, laravel uses that name elsewhere in the framework, duh, so when it tries to call my model it is actually calling the other session class from somewhere deep in the framework.  some of the solutions i found suggest namespaces but I dont think that will work for me because the relationship declaration simply passes a string with the class name to the framework.  I think this means that the calling of the class happens elsewhere and I would need to put the namespace /use there correct me if I am wrong please.

either way changing the session class to Sessionss and changing the relationships to suit has resolved my issue.

i hope this helps someone else not waste 36 hours trying to figure this out :p

Comment: namespacing will work. Laravel will respect the namespace in the relationship even if you are providing a string.